# Insert null to integer type column in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

i am trying to modify an insert statement in Redshift. I added a column at the end of table. Previous last column is one of type integer, which I do not need to handle in my insert (has remained null so far). Can I insert null values to it somehow? The 'NULL AS[...]' expression obviously fails, with error message:

Amazon Invalid operation: column "search_result_size" is of type integer but expression is of type text;

Alternatively, I will try to skip this column during insert statement, but I prefer to declare its value as null each time. I have been searching this for quite some time now, no solution found so far. Any ideas would be greatly welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Simply use `null`, eg `INSERT INTO t(a, b) SELECT 1, null;`. Adding quotes around it makes it a `text` value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `null` keyword:

```
insert into the_table (col_1, col_2, col_3)
values (1, 2, null);
```

If you want to change the value for existing rows, you need UPDATE:

```
update the_table
    set the_column = null
where ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually managed to solve this by using CAST. So, I did:

[...],
CAST (NULL AS INTEGER) AS column_name,
[...]

It works fine now. I believe it could be considered a valid approach.

Comment: You Do not need to cast NULL as Integer. It is redundant.

Comment: the NULL as column_name expression is handled as text from Redshift, so I had to CAST Null as Integer for it to be accepted as a proper data type.

Comment: What exactly is your full statement? "insert into yourtable select ...., null as column_name;"

Answer (score 0):

Use `NULL` and specify `NULL`'s type; by default it's converted to `NULL` of `VARCHAR(MAX)`.

For example, `SELECT 'a', 3, null::INT, null::BOOL, null;` returns result below.

[image]

*I'm using workbench/j, so I can show each column type in resultset*